# Using the scanf() function

Tags: c, scanf

I intend to modify each other letter of a particular string. But for the purposes of this program none of that occurs. So far I've grabbed a string from the user and stored it in `userinput` and intend to print it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {    
char userinput[256] ="";
printf("Enter somthing to change:\n");
scanf("%s", &userinput);
printf("%s\n", userinput);

int k = 2; // This is just here to do something every time k is even
int j = strlen(userinput);
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {

    if(k % 2 == 0) {
        printf("%s", userinput[i]);
        k++;
    }
    else {
        printf("%s", userinput[i]);
        k++;
    }
}

}
```

The `strlen()` function however does not work on the `userinput`. I figure this is because `strlen()` is supposed to take the address of the first char of a string and then iterate until reaching a null char but scanf doesn't actually create a null char.
I couldn't figure out a way of adding the `'\0'` after the string without first knowing the length of the string.

How would I go about accessing the length of a stored character sequence if it's stored in an array?

Comment: "The `strlen()` function however does not work on the `userinput`" In what way? `strlen(userinput)` is - unless the input overran the array - a valid call.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This:

```
scanf("%s", &userinput);
```

should be:

```
scanf("%s", userinput);
```

The address of operator `&` is unrequired, and incorrect. Arrays decay to the address of their first element when passed to a function. `scanf("%s")` will append a null terminating character so it is unnecessary to explicitly insert one.

To prevent potential buffer overrun specify the maximum number of characters that `scanf()` should write to `userinput`. This should be one less than the size of `userinput`, leaving room for the terminating null character:

```
scanf("%255s", userinput);
```

The incorrect format specifier (which is undefined behaviour) is being used to print the `char`acters of `userinput`: use `%c` not `%s`. This:

```
printf("%s", userinput[i]);
```

must be:

```
printf("%c", userinput[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
scanf("%s", &userinput);
```

with

```
scanf("%s", userinput);
```

we have to use addresses for `scanf`:

- If we will scan into an `int a` then we have to call `scanf()` with the address of `a` => `&a`
- If we will scan into a `double a` then we have to call `scanf()` with the address of `a` => `&a`
- But If we will scan data into with pointer (memory address) `int *a;` or char array `char a[50];` then we have to call `scanf()` with the pointer or with the array without adding `&`

From the [scanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) page

> Depending on the format string, the function may expect a sequence of
>   additional arguments, each containing a pointer to allocated storage
>   where the interpretation of the extracted characters is stored with
>   the appropriate type. There should be at least as many of these
>   arguments as the number of values stored by the format specifiers.
>   Additional arguments are ignored by the function. These arguments are
>   expected to be pointers: to store the result of a scanf operation on a
>   regular variable, its name should be preceded by the reference
>   operator (&) (see example).

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I think I was a little confused with my initial declaration of `char userinput[256]`. If I'm correct it is the pointer to the first char of an array but it doesn't need to be declared as such. Which is why when I went to store it I thought i needed to give the address

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
scanf("%s", &userinput);
```

to

```
scanf("%s", userinput);
```

The `&` operator is not required in the case of String capture. The `scanf()` automatically appends the null character(`'\0'`) to the end of the string so `int j = strlen(userinput);` should work.

If you still want to calculate the length without this function efficiently here is the link [How to calculate the length of a string in C efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2070566/2006839)

Answer (score 1):

You're confused about types, as others have indicated. Using scanf and printf when you're confused about types is dangerous!

> scanf("%s", &userinput);

The type of `&userinput` is `char (*)[256]`, but scanf expects `%s` to correspond to a `char *`. Since the type expected and the type given differ and aren't required to have the same representation, the behaviour is undefined.

> I figure this is because strlen is supposed to take the address of the
>   first char of a string and then iterate until reaching a null char but
>   scanf doesn't actually create a null char.

Wrong. scanf certainly does assign a null character, when you use the `%s` format specifier. That is, providing scanf doesn't encounter an error or EOF. On that note, you should probably check for errors from scanf:

```
if (scanf("%s", userinput) != 1) {
    /* Insert error handling here */
}
```

... as you should with *all* standard library functions in C.

`k` is pointless. Your loop already increments `i` at the same frequency as `k`.

strlen returns a `size_t`. Make sure you store return values in the right types. If a function returns `size_t`, then you store the return value in `size_t`. If a function returns `int`, then you store the return value in an `int`. Got it? Whatever the return type is, is whatever type you use to store the return type. Use the manual to find that out.

> `printf("%s", userinput[i]);`

There's that type confusion again. `userinput[i]` is a `char`. `%s` tells printf to expect a `char *`. When the argument is invalid, the behaviour is undefined. That may cause your program to malfunction. Consider `printf("%c", userinput[i]);` or `printf("%s", &userinput[i]);`.