# Signed integer overflow: 999999999 * 10 cannot be represented in type 'int' Error

Tags: c, integer-overflow, cs50

Why is there a runtime error? I made `range2` a long long.

**Code:**

```
/*VARIABLES FOR WHILE LOOP*/
 long long range1 = 9;
 int length = 1;

 /*FIND NUM'S LENGTH*/
 while (NUM > range1)     
 {
    long long range2 = range1 * 10 + 9;
    length += 1;
 }
```

**Error:**

> credit.c:25:25: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 999999999 * 10 cannot be represented in type 'int'

Comment: `length += 1` - how large can that get?

Comment: I want the limit to be  the length of NUM (a credit card number entered by the user).

Comment: What compiler are you using? `999999999 * 10` is too large to be stored in a `signed int`, but since `range1` is a `signed long long`, it should suffice.

Comment: Try changing the `10` to `10LL`.

Comment: @moswald: I'm using cs50's IDE. I used 'LL', but it still gave the error.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this one to handle the above conditions

*With the two most common representations, the range is 0 through 4,294,967,295 (2^32 − 1) for representation as an (unsigned) binary number, and −2,147,483,648 (−2^31) through 2,147,483,647 (2^31 − 1) for representation as two's complement*

I'm recently faced it while solving a question having constraints

> Given a 32-bit signed integer, reverse digits of an integer

**runtime error: signed integer overflow: 999999999 * 10 cannot be represented in type 'int'**

So, here is my code

```
    while (x != 0) {
        int pop = x % 10;
        x /= 10;
        if (rev > INT_MAX/10 || (rev == INT_MAX / 10 && pop > 7)) return 0;
        if (rev < INT_MIN/10 || (rev == INT_MIN / 10 && pop < -8)) return 0;
        rev = rev * 10 + pop;
    }
```

before I'm getting 999999999*10, rev>INT_MAX it guaranteed OVERFLOW & vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

There are (two) major problems with your code, which both lead to the same error:
The int `length` variable is being increased to a point where it reaches the max values.

Here is you while loop:

```
while (NUM > range1)
{
    long long range2 = range1 * 10 + 9;
    length += 1;
}
```

#### Problem #1

This biggest issue is that this while loop will never end. You never change the values of `NUM` or `range1` in the while loop, so if `NUM` starts out as greater than `range1`, you will get stuck in an infinite loop. `length += 1` will keep getting called until the `length` integer reaches the max allowed int value.

#### (Possible) Problem #2

Depending on how you fix Problem #1, you can also face the following issue.

As you stated in a comment above, `NUM` is a credit card number.

- Credit card number by default are
  16 digits long.
- The max value of and `int` variable is 999999999 *
  10 which is max 10 digits.

If your loop is set to run the value of `NUM` times until it reaches 9. If we let's say pick the lowest possible 16 digit credit card number, 1000000000000000, your loop still will still run `1000000000000000 - 9` times.

Every time your loop runs, `length` is increased by 1. The loop will basically try to increase the int variable at least  999999999999991 times which will cause the value to become greater than 999999999 * 10.

#### (Possible) Fix

There are not enough details in your question to know if for sure this is what will solve your problem, but I will guess that instead of

```
long long range2 = range1 * 10 + 9;
```

you probably meant to write

```
range1 = range1 * 10 + 9;
```

Comment: length gets increased only to the NUM's length (digits). My loop is supposed to find the NUM's number of digits.

Comment: @KhalidMukadam That is not what your loop currently does. To be clear, if let's say your NUM is 16 digits long, should length end up as 16 or should it be `16 - range1` and only be 5?

Comment: @KhalidMukadam Problem #1 explains why you are getting a runtime error and in essense answers your question. It seems though that there are more problems with your code than you indicated in your question. If you are looking for the proper way to find the length of a string, look at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070566/how-to-calculate-the-length-of-a-string-in-c-efficiently

Answer (score 0):

You have to carefully read the question because in some question input/output is signed 32-bit integer or unsigned 32-bit integer both have a different range
so value outside the range is invalid or you have to return 0 just like bellow
e.g.
Given a signed 32-bit integer x, return x with its digits reversed. If reversing x causes the value to go outside the signed 32-bit integer range [-231, 231 - 1], then return 0.

Assume the environment does not allow you to store 64-bit integers (signed or unsigned).
[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeDaE.png)

Answer (score -1):

Size of unsigned int is (0 to 4,294,967,295) for 4 bytes;
So 999999999 *10 is greater than 4,294,967,295
therefore try using (long)

```
long long int x=999999999 *10   (try this...)
```